# is it possible to write a launcher app for Honeycomb that retains its settings

Tags: android, launcher

I'm curious if Android allows for the creation of an app that locks down the environment in a way so as to make it that every time you reboot the device it goes back to the preset configuration, removing any apps that may have been installed in the previous run, and resetting all settings.  I haven't seen any home apps for Honeycomb, I'm wondering if it's possible to even skin that OS.

Specifically this is for a store kiosk app that would allow users to play with the device but could easily be "reset" in the event that someone installs something unwanted, or sets the home page in the browser to something unsavory.

I see a [link](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/install-foliomod-custom-android-rom-on-toshiba-folio-100-tablet/) to a custom ROM that someone has written for the Toshiba tablet, is this the route I'd have to take, and if so, where do I get started on this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honeycomb is no different than previous versions of Android and you can write a custom Launcher. What you cannot do however is install/uninstall apps without the user's consent. You would need to build a custom version of Android to have the permissions to do this.

Comment: I think this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#wipeData(int) is relevant to the topic as well, but I'll accept your answer.